# My nav bar contents are not centering on my logo. How would I fix this? CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

I noticed my nav bar links were a bit off-centered with my logo on the left. Would someone explain to me how I can fix this? I attached a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2BvP.jpg) and code snippets. I tried doing inline-block and float but still jacked things up. Should I position them using the x and y offsets or not? I just want to do this in the best and most organized way.

```css
/*Font for logo*/
@font-face {
    font-family: 'leander';
    src: url(/Fonts/LEANDER.TTF);
}

/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #141414;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px black;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/*Style for website logo*/
.logo {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'leander', sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
}

/*CSS style for the body*/
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #262626; }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Arclight Web Development</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="topnav">
    <div class = "logo">
        <span id="A">A</span>
        <span id="R">R</span>
        <span id="R">C</span>
        <span id="R">L</span>
        <span id="R">I</span>
        <span id="R">G</span>
        <span id="R">H</span>
        <span id="R">T</span>
    </div>
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
    <a href="#about">Meet the Dev</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Off-centered how? Where did you expect them to end up?

Comment: The nav links are not centered vertically on the logo itself. They are slightly above the center line.

Comment: They look vertically centered to me, but you can lower them by increasing the line height, e.g. `.topnav a { line-height: 22px; }`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use

> display: grid;

in topnav selector, its common way to make navbar.

Sparate the nav size by giving `

> grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;

also you need to wrap your nav bar links to single `<div></div>`.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'leander';
  src: url(/Fonts/LEANDER.TTF);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #262626;
}

.topnav {
  /* position: relative; */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  background-color: #141414;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  text-align: right;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px black;
}

.topnav a {
  /* position: relative; */
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.logo {
  /* position: absolute; */
  /* top: 50%; Important for vertical centered element */
  /* transform: translateY(-50%); vertically centered */
  color: white;
  font-family: 'leander', sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  /* float: left; */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Arclight Web Development</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="topnav">
      <div class="logo">
        <span id="A">A</span>
        <span id="R">R</span>
        <span id="R">C</span>
        <span id="R">L</span>
        <span id="R">I</span>
        <span id="R">G</span>
        <span id="R">H</span>
        <span id="R">T</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
        <a href="#about">Meet the Dev</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

the easy way to archive this result is to use either flex or grid.
you can for example add `nav` element to wrap Links something like

```
<div class="topnav">
<div class="logo">
  <span id="A">A</span>
  <span id="R">R</span>
  <span id="C">C</span>
  <span id="L">L</span>
  <span id="I">I</span>
  <span id="G">G</span>
  <span id="H">H</span>
  <span id="T">T</span>
</div>
<nav>
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
  <a href="#about">Meet the Dev</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

and than in you CSS you can use `flex` to align element inside `topnav` like so

```
.topnav {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: space-around;
```

}

`align-items:center` in this case will take of center elements in cross axis

Answer (score -1):

Give `position: absolute;` to `.logo`.

Center the **logo** by adding `top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);` properties to `.logo`.

Rest of code was organized from start.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'leander';
  src: url(/Fonts/LEANDER.TTF);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #262626;
}

.topnav {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #141414;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px black;
}

.topnav a {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; /*Important for vertical centered element*/
  transform: translateY(-50%); /*vertically centered*/
  color: white;
  font-family: 'leander', sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Arclight Web Development</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="topnav">
    <div class="logo">
      <span id="A">A</span>
      <span id="R">R</span>
      <span id="C">C</span>
      <span id="L">L</span>
      <span id="I">I</span>
      <span id="G">G</span>
      <span id="H">H</span>
      <span id="T">T</span>
    </div>
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
    <a href="#about">Meet the Dev</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Code only answers are considered low quality. Without sufficient explaination, your answer is hard to understand.
If the OP can't understand your answer, then he also won't be able to reproduce your possible solution. As such it 
would be worthless to him/her. Please add a sufficient explaination of your possible solution. Then your snippet is nothing like the intended outcome. The links are not centered

Comment: I was adding the explanation but I accidentally hit the _Post your Answer_ Button.

Comment: still far away from the intend outcome. The links are not centered. Then on a technical level a poor solution to vertical center a log with absolute positioning. The mdoern approach is to simply use Flexbox which would solve the entire issue.

Comment: I used flexbox first. But outcome was not intended by OP. And Links are centered. It aligns all links either to center, right or left

Comment: did you ever try to use grid-template-column? @ShreyBhangale

Comment: I used `grid-template-column` many times, But not in above snippet. I thought Grid in navbar is bit too much.

Comment: i dont think its too much if you still only use plain css [my suggest](https://codepen.io/scdafee/pen/yLKBNmp)

Comment: Hmm... Really it not bit too much